# R - Caret RFE gives "task 1 failed - Stopping" error when using pickSizeBest

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, rfe

I am using Caret R package to train an SVM modell. My code is as follows:

```
options(show.error.locations = TRUE)    
svmTrain <- function(svmType, subsetSizes, data, seeds, metric){
        svmFuncs$summary <- function(...) c(twoClassSummary(...), defaultSummary(...), prSummary(...))

    data_x <- data.frame(data[,2:ncol(data)])
    data_y <- unlist(data[,1])

    FSctrl <- rfeControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 10,
                     rerank = TRUE,
                     verbose = TRUE,
                     functions = svmFuncs,
                     saveDetails = TRUE,
                     seeds = seeds
    )

    TRctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                       savePredictions = TRUE,
                       classProbs = TRUE,
                       verboseIter = TRUE,
                       sampling = "down",
                       number = 10,
                       search = "random",
                       repeats = 3,
                       returnResamp = "all",
                       allowParallel = TRUE
    )
    svmProf <- rfe( x = data_x,
                y = data_y,
                sizes = subsetSizes,
                metric = metric,
                rfeControl = FSctrl,
                method = svmType,
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                trControl = TRctrl,
                selectSize = pickSizeBest(data, metric = "AUC", maximize = TRUE),
                tuneLength = 5
    )
}

data1a = openTable(3, 'a')
data1b = openTable(3, 'b')
data = rbind(data1a, data1b)

last <- roundToTens(ncol(data)-1)
subsetSizes <- c( 3:9, seq(10, last, 10) )

svmTrain <- svmTrain("svmRadial", subsetSizes, data, seeds, "AUC")
```

When I comment out pickSizeBest row, the algorithm runs fine. However, when I do not comment, it gives the following error:

```
Error in { (from svm.r#58) : task 1 failed - "Stopping"
```

Row 58 is `svmProf <- rfe( x = data_x,..`

I tried to look up if I use pickSizeBest the wrong way, but I cannot find the problem. Could somebody help me?

Many thanks!

EDIT: I just realized that `pickSizeBest (data, ...)` should not use `data`.  However, I still do not know what should be add there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your example, but I would suggest that you just pass the function `pickSizeBest`, i.e.:

[...]

```
trControl = TRctrl,
selectSize = pickSizeBest,
tuneLength = 5
```

[...]

The functionality is described here: 
http://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html#backwards-selection

Comment: It works that way, however, when I look at the fitted modell, it says 'Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.' But I would like to use AUC instead.

Comment: I would have expected the `metric` argument of `rfe()` to be passed down. I would need a minimum working example to help you further, though.

Comment: Thanks, I think, I got a workaround. If I do not pass all 3 functions to svmFuncs$summary, only prSummary that calculates AUC, than it would use AUC. I also expected that if I use AUC, it would not matter whether I calculate other metrices, however, for some reasons it does not work that way.